# C# why cant i open windows fax and scanner?

Tags: c#, winforms

So i have tried this from another question. but it is still giving me the error of Win32exception was unhandled. The system cannot find the file specified. Here is my code.

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\‪WFS.exe";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Can you navigate manually to that file path?

Comment: Yes it is in here: C:\Windows\system32 i am using windows 10. it is named WFS.exe

Comment: Catch the exception & see if you get any more information.

Comment: It only says Erroe: The system cannot find the specified file.

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  [You don't prefer it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

Comment: Oh changing the Platform target to any CPU works for me.